# Трудности со знаками препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется диалог:
—Как ты сюда попал?
—Через дверь() как!
И вот, какой знак препинания должен быть перед "как"? Я склоняюсь к тире.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пунктуационные знаки - принадлежность письменной речи, поэтому при передаче устной речи (с ее синтаксическими особенностями) не всегда легко дать однозначный ответ или сослаться на конкретное правило. Но я бы тире не поставила. Никаких смысловых оттенков, характерных для предложений с тире,   здесь нет: ни причинно-следственных, ни противопоставления. Хотя тире часто используется как авторский знак, заменяя собой запятую или двоеточие.

Comment: Автор, видимо, видит (слышит?) здесь период или перебой интонации. Но я бы тоже тире здесь не поставил, хотя вообще люблю этот знак.

Comment: И я тоже!!

Answer (score 0):

Запятую ставьте, Ни для чего другого здесь нет никаких оснований.

Answer (score 0):

Господа, а не кроется ли в этом "как" выражение "а как иначе"? *Через дверь, а как иначе я сюда попаду?*
Рассмотрим подобные случаи и сравним. *И как ты столько километров протопал? - Ногами, как (а как иначе?)!*
*И кому ты только, такой хороший,  достанешься?! - Тебе, кому (кому же ещё я достанусь)!*
Получается, что "как" - это неполное предложение, перед ним надо поставить запятую, потому что "Через дверь, как!" - это сложное предложение, состоящее из двух неполных простых.

Comment: Возможно. Но мы все сошлись на запятой.